# How to add all value in a column in database and get its average then count its num of rows

Tags: php, mysqli

I got a query code which select rated from db rating then I add all of it using the variable total then what Im trying to do is I want to get the num of rows in db so I can divide the num of rows to the total value to get its average

```
$total=0;
    <?php
$st='SELECT rated FROM rating;';
$t=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($t,$st);
mysqli_stmt_execute($t);
$res=mysqli_stmt_get_result($t);
while($rop=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){

$total+=$rop['rated'];
echo $total;
$count=count($rop['rated']);
}
echo $total;
$total=0;
```

I then got an error parameter must be an array or object that implements countable in $count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
count($rop['rated'])
```

does not make sense. You try to count a value.

You should have a look at the mysql avg function: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp

```
select avg(rated) from rating;
```

should do the job for you

Answer (score 0):

The `count()` function is for counting the number of elements in an array.

You should be incrementing the variable each time through the loop.

```
$count = 0;
while($rop=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $total+=$rop['rated'];
    echo $total;
    $count++;
}
```

But there's no need to do this in PHP, you can just do it in MySQL:

```
SELECT SUM(rated) AS total, AVG(rated) AS avg, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM rating
```